# React Multiple instances of same component receive different data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a view where I need to render the same component multiple times and maintain a specific order.

The component `<LargeImageContent />` is the component to be rendered multiple times.

Please see my data structure where data is managed within state - this is just a prototype so this works for now.

My initial thought on rendering multiple instances of the same component is to `.map()` through the data however, this will render the component one after another.

I need the components to receive the correct data for each and maintain the structure seen below.

Here is my layout container:

```
export default class Layout extends Component {
    state = {
        data: {
            largeImageObjs: [
                {
                    obj1: {
                        image: '',
                        heading: 'Hi there',
                        text: 'Perpetua efficiantur in quo, vix cu stet denique repudiandae, sonet zril te usu.',
                        btnLabel: 'Shop now'
                    },
                    obj2: {
                        image: '',
                        heading: 'Different Heading',
                        text: 'Efficiantur in quo, vix cu stet denique repudiandae, sonet zril te usu.',
                        btnLabel: 'Order now'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="layout-wrap">
                <Header />
                <LargeImageContent data={this.state.data} />
                <SmallPanelContent />
                <FourColContent />
                <LargeImageContent data={this.state.data} />
                <SmallPanelContent />
                <GridCarousel />
                <LargeImageContent data={this.state.data} />
                <LargeImageContent data={this.state.data} />
                <LargeImageContent data={this.state.data} />
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here is the LargImageContent component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import Button from '../Button';

import './index.scss';

export default class LargeImageContent extends Component {
    render() {
        const { data } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="large-image-content-wrap">
                <div className="large-image-content">
                    <div className="large-image-content-body">
                        <h2>{data.heading}</h2>
                        <p>{data.text}</p>
                        <Button theme="button-primary" label={data.btnLabel} icon={'/svg/icons/arrow-right.svg'} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you want to share more about the problem? "Receive different data" is not very descriptive.

Comment: See the example of data presented within state.

Comment: what do you mean by `I need the components to receive the correct data for each` do you want to send an obj1 for first instance and obj2 for 2nd and so on or anything different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data as you modeled it and use it in your LargeImageContent Component you should do this:

```
        <div className="layout-wrap">
            <Header />
            <LargeImageContent data={this.state.data.largeImageObjs[0].obj1} />
            <SmallPanelContent />
            <FourColContent />
            <LargeImageContent data={this.state.data.largeImageObjs[0].obj2} />
            <SmallPanelContent />
            <GridCarousel />
              ...
            <Footer />
        </div>
```